# require_once() Failed Opening Resource in Laravel Valet-hosted project

Tags: php, laravel

I am just picking up using Laravel, but I dont like Vue and have been working with the React ecosystem and would like to use React instead of Vue. Laravel Mix doesnt give me the setup I want and so I figured I could use create-react-app.
Using Laravel Valet, I have started a project in which I have also installed create-react-app in a folder called ui, at the root of the Laravel installation.

My idea is to forego some of Laravel's functionality, namely the whole frontend.

I am attempting to require the react app build html file in `resources/views/main.blade.php` like so:
`require_once __DIR__.'/ui/build/index.html';`

This gives me the error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   (E_UNKNOWN) Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine::main(): Failed opening
>   required
>   '/Users/Username/Sites/sitename/storage/framework/views/ui/build/index.html'
>   (include_path='.:')

This path is not correct, but I'm not sure why it is inserting `/storage/framework/` into that path.

I have also tried the following, each with a similar error of `Failed opening resource`:

`require_once('../../ui/build/index.html');`
`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ui/build/index.html');`
`require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/ui/build/index.html');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel does not integrate with Vue, and Laravel Mix is a simple layer on top of Webpack. The default Laravel application ships with Vue scaffolding but removing that is as simple as deleting the files in `resources/assets/js` and if you wish to use another Javascript library then you can add that into your `app.js` instead.

The error you're receiving is because Laravel caches view files, meaning that they're served from the cache directory (which lives in `storage/framework`) so references like `__DIR__` are referencing the cache directory, not the resources directory. You can see this [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views):

> You should avoid using the **DIR** and **FILE** constants in your Blade views, since they will refer to the location of the cached, compiled view.

The correct approach to include files into your views with Blade is using the `@include` directive, e.g:

```
@include('ui.build.index')
```

Also, worth noting, that any time you *do* need to obtain the path to a file in your Laravel application you should use the [`base_path`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-base-path) and [`app_path`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-app-path) helpers.

Prior to continuing with development of your application you should read through the [JavaScript & CSS Scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend) documentation and the [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade) documentation, as they contain a lot of information that will be very useful to you — for example, it explains how to replace Vue with React using a single command.

Comment: And correct approach to remove scaffolding is to use `php artisan preset none`.

Comment: Hi Sam,thanks, sometimes I find the docs tough to connect the dots with.  
I understand that I can use `php artisan preset none` to remove the scaffolding, but if I use the `php artisan preset react` all it does is add the babel preset to the webpack config -- which doesnt really accomplish what I want. 
I have opened an issue on github about this actually: [https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1516]

Thanks for the explanation about `__DIR__` and your suggestion regarding `base_path` worked as so:
`include(base_path('ui/build/index.html'));`